# Content Compliance for Google Groups?

Tags: google-workspace, google-groups, google-cloud-dlp

My company is migrating to GSuite and we have some Content Compliance rules that we need to enforce. We previously enforced these with an email security appliance using Exchange as the platform. The DLP rules for normal Gmail work just fine, but we have a group that is too large to use a shared mailbox, so we've converted them to a Google Group.

I can't find any way to apply any DLP settings to Groups. I've tried creating Gmail rules that apply only to the Group, but those don't work at all. Has anyone done this or know of any way to accomplish with Groups?